# React Router NotFound Route not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to extend my very basic **working** router, such that it can handle invalid page requests. For example, if the user appends the homepage url with *'/about'* the address bar they will be taken to the correct page.

```
const Routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="about" component={AboutPage} />
      <Route path="authors" component={AuthorPage} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
  </Router>
)
```

However, if the user mistypes, say '/aboutt', they should be shown the NotFoundPage. Well, that is the intention, but it is not working. Instead of showing the NotFoundPage component all I see is:

```
Cannot GET /aboutt
```

I can render the NotFoundPage component if I modify the navbar code, but changing the address bar doesn't work as I would expect.

Edit:

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/2108) on Github.

Comment: You must configure your server to direct all traffic to your index file for rect-router can run that function. Is NodeJS?

Comment: Good to know. I thought I was doing something wrong. My setup uses gulp-connect to set up a web server.